# Docker / AWS SAM Cli problem on Mac Silicon

Tags: docker, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, apple-silicon

Would anyone have encountered problems running Lambda function locally with AWS Sam Cli on Mac Silicon arm64 ?

I think my problem comes from my Docker install :

`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/build?t=public.ecr.aws%2Fsam%2Femulation-nodejs14.x%3Arapid-1.70.0-arm64&q=False&nocache=False&rm=True&forcerm=False&pull=True&platform=linux%2Farm64`

I freshly received my new MacBook, restored from TimeMachine backup of my old Intel MacBook, and uninstalled / reinstalled few softwares like Docker to make sure I have native arm64 software.

I try to run sam local invoke --template _aws_sam/template.yml TestLambda
And get the following result a "Building Image Failed" :

```
Invoking index.handler (nodejs14.x)
Image was not found.
Removing rapid images for repo public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs14.x
Building image...
Failed to build Docker Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/build?t=public.ecr.aws%2Fsam%2Femulation-nodejs14.x%3Arapid-1.70.0-arm64&q=False&nocache=False&rm=True&forcerm=False&pull=True&platform=linux%2Farm64

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/lambda_image.py", line 273, in _build_image
    for log in resp_stream:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 354, in _stream_helper
    yield self._result(response, json=decode)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway ("b'Bad response from Docker engine'")
Error: Building Image failed.
```

Here's my full debug trace :

```
2023-01-21 21:01:09,197 | Config file location: /Users/marc/localdev/microservices/_aws_sam/samconfig.toml
2023-01-21 21:01:09,197 | Config file '/Users/marc/localdev/microservices/_aws_sam/samconfig.toml' does not exist
2023-01-21 21:01:09,212 | Using config file: samconfig.toml, config environment: default
2023-01-21 21:01:09,212 | Expand command line arguments to:
2023-01-21 21:01:09,212 | --template_file=/Users/marc/localdev/microservices/_aws_sam/template.yml --function_logical_id=TestLambda --no_event --layer_cache_basedir=/Users/marc/.aws-sam/layers-pkg --container_host=localhost --container_host_interface=127.0.0.1 
2023-01-21 21:01:09,212 | local invoke command is called
2023-01-21 21:01:09,213 | No Parameters detected in the template
2023-01-21 21:01:09,223 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource TestLambda, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-21 21:01:09,223 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource LambdaFunctionOverHttps, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-21 21:01:09,223 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-21 21:01:09,223 | 0 stacks found in the template
2023-01-21 21:01:09,223 | No Parameters detected in the template
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource TestLambda, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource LambdaFunctionOverHttps, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | 3 resources found in the stack 
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | Found Serverless function with name='TestLambda' and CodeUri='../lambda/test'
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri ../lambda/test relative to /Users/marc/localdev/microservices/_aws_sam/template.yml
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | Found Serverless function with name='LambdaFunctionOverHttps' and CodeUri='../lambda/marketplaceStatsExpose'
2023-01-21 21:01:09,229 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri ../lambda/marketplaceStatsExpose relative to /Users/marc/localdev/microservices/_aws_sam/template.yml
2023-01-21 21:01:09,242 | Found one Lambda function with name 'TestLambda'
2023-01-21 21:01:09,242 | Invoking index.handler (nodejs14.x)
2023-01-21 21:01:09,242 | No environment variables found for function 'TestLambda'
2023-01-21 21:01:09,242 | Loading AWS credentials from session with profile 'None'
2023-01-21 21:01:09,247 | Resolving code path. Cwd=/Users/marc/localdev/microservices/_aws_sam, CodeUri=/Users/marc/localdev/microservices/lambda/test
2023-01-21 21:01:09,247 | Resolved absolute path to code is /Users/marc/localdev/microservices/lambda/test
2023-01-21 21:01:09,247 | Code /Users/marc/localdev/microservices/lambda/test is not a zip/jar file
2023-01-21 21:01:09,254 | Image was not found.
2023-01-21 21:01:09,254 | Removing rapid images for repo public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs14.x
Building image...
2023-01-21 21:01:09,908 | Failed to build Docker Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/build?t=public.ecr.aws%2Fsam%2Femulation-nodejs14.x%3Arapid-1.70.0-arm64&q=False&nocache=False&rm=True&forcerm=False&pull=True&platform=linux%2Farm64

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/lambda_image.py", line 273, in _build_image
    for log in resp_stream:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 354, in _stream_helper
    yield self._result(response, json=decode)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.70.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway ("b'Bad response from Docker engine'")
2023-01-21 21:01:09,913 | Cleaning all decompressed code dirs
2023-01-21 21:01:09,913 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
Error: Building Image failed.
```

So many thanks if someone could help me out !!!

I've tried to manually pull

```
docker pull public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x:1.70.0-arm64
```

but it's not the same image as the one required.

I've tried

```
docker pull public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x:rapid-1.70.0-arm64
```

But it doesn't exist :

```
Error response from daemon: failed to resolve reference "public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x:rapid-1.70.0-arm64": public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x:rapid-1.70.0-arm64: not found
```

I've tried to change `Architectures:`in `template.yaml` to `arm64` but it still fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally removed Docker from my computer, and installed an older Docker version (4.7.0), and it worked.

Old Docker version 4.7.0 is available here:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#470

Answer (score 0):

Try to put :

`platform: linux/x86_64` in your yml file.

Example:

`front: build: ./azure-vote **platform: linux/x86_64** image: registry.azurecr.io/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1 container_name: vote-front environment: REDIS: vote-back ports: - "80:80"`